# Embedded Youtube Video with custom buttons and autoplay at the start

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embedding

I've been trying to emulate this: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zawHg

This works when the video is muted, however when I try and remove the &mute=1 in the URL, the video will no longer play.

original:
`<iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FKWwdQu6_ok?enablejsapi=1&html5=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

adapted:
`<iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FKWwdQu6_ok?enablejsapi=1&html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I'm not sure why this is happening.

The expected outcome I'm trying to achieve is on page load, the video starts automatically (with sound), but can be controlled with the custom play/ pause buttons thank you!

Comment: If this isn't possible, happy to forgo the autoplay but would really like to be able to control the buttons!

Comment: Copy of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754132/cant-play-youtube-video-through-iframe-api-when-video-is-unmute
The answer fixes your problem

Comment: sorry, it seems it still doesn't work with autoplay on.

Comment: Bah, ok - thanks for your time!